# Readers Writers - who is getting preference

Tags: c, mutex, semaphore

The code is:

```
Semaphore rsem = 1;
Semaphore wsem = 1;
Semaphore mutex_rc = 1;
Semaphore mutex wc = 1;
Semaphore other_readers = 1;
int rc = 0;
int wc = 0;

void reader(void)
{
    while(true)
    {
        down(other_readers);
        down(rsem);
        down(mutex_rc);
        rc++;
        if(rc == 1)
            down(wsem);
        up(mutex_rc);
        up(rsem);
        up(other_readers);
        read_data_base();
        down(mutex_rc);
        rc--;
        if(rc == 0)
            up(wsem);
        up(mutex_rc);
    }
}



void writer()
{
    while(true)
    {
        down(mutex_wc);
        wc++;
        if(wc == 1)
            down(rsem);
        up(mutex_wc);
        down(wsem);
        write_data_base();
        up(wsem);
        down(mutex_wc);
        wc--;
        if(wc == 0)
            up(rsem);
        up(mutex_wc);
    }
}
```

I have to tell who is getting the preference. I understand semaphores and what they are used for but I can't tell who is getting the preference here.
And what is the reason for the other_readers semaphore?
What is the approach to such problems?

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. What files are you including? How is the data type `Semaphore` defined? How are the functions `down`, `up`, `read_data_base` and `write_data_base` defined? Or is this supposed to be pseudo-code?

Comment: This is exactly how I have it in my homework. But, ofcourse, assume everything is defined well. Semaphore is `typedef int semaphore;`, `write_data_base` is just some method that writes something to the data base